# Need the nearest integer value in javascript

Tags: javascript, ceil

In my javascript pagination file I was calculating number of pages by `Math.ceil()`

```
        var total_pages = Math.ceil(total_items/items_per_page);
```

But here I am getting 3 for 2.25, 1 for 0.588, 2 for 1.01 etc. But i need to get 2 for 2.25 and 1 for 1.01. So how can I check that in JavaScript.

**Actual**

3 for 2.25
1 for 0.588
1 for 1.088
2 for 1.01

**Required**

2 for 2.25
1 for 0.588
1 for 1.088
1 for 1.01

Comment: You're expecting 1 from 1.088 and also 1 from 0.588. Why is this?

Comment: He needs to round it. Everything x.50 and above will go to larger number and everything under x.50 will go to smaller number.

Comment: @MattDiamant : Yes , as 1 is the nearest integer to 1.088 and 0.588

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round it.

```
var total_pages = Math.round(total_items/items_per_page);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use Javascript `toFixed()` method?

```
var num = total_items/items_per_page;
var total_pages = num.toFixed(0);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sohelkhalifa/PwxSP/3/)
[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Add 0.5 to the number and then take the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.round(Your Number).. It will round off your number .. I mean 2.2 to 2 , 1.6 to 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Math.floor() instead of Math.ceil()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Answer (score 0):

ceil will return next number ,floor will return before number

```
 Example:

 Math.ceil(2.2) = 3;
 Math.floor(2.2) = 2;
```